# append object and bones and add the bones to the main rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have 2 blender projects. In the first one I have my character rigged with a metarig (Rigify), with all body parts modelled except hands. In the second one I have a hand rigged with hand bones. I want to import the second into the first, join the hands with the rest of the character's body, and incorporate the hand bones into the metarig. How do I do this? Sorry if my terminology is not accurate I'm not very experienced with Blender

Comment: what does it give if you join (Ctrl J)? Also you'll have to parent the hand bone to the arm bone

Comment: parenting the hand bone to the arm bone works, thank you! but if I join them they stop working. I suppose I don't really need them to be the same armature as long as they work so that's solved, however, when I append, the hand objects shift out of position with the hand bones. is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: metarig or generated rig?  'metarig' is the rig you get when you add a rigify armature as a new armature.  Generated rig is the one you get when you apply generate.  Normally you want to use the generated rig and join the bones to it.

Comment: @MartyFouts it's metarig. what is a generated rig? where do I find the option to add a generated rig

Comment: If you use Rigify, you pose the metarig, and then there's a button you can press to generate the actual rig you want to use.  The metarig is a simple rig that only has the deforming bones.  The generated rig has all of the controls. [Generating the Rig](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/basics.html#generating-the-rig) in the manual talks about how to generate a rig.